# Lightweight Alternative to XmlTextReader.ReadElementContentAsBinHex?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, clr, xmlreader

I'm running into a problem with memory bloat using XmlTextReader.ReadElementContentAsBinHex.  Let me first say that I'm not using hex by choice, but as a result of needing to interop with a legacy system.

```
int read;
var buffer = new byte[4096];
while((read = reader.ReadElementContentAsBinHex(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

For element contents of size greater than 64M or so I get an OutOfMemoryException that seems to be related to the accumulation of allocations within the reader's internal StringBuilder.  Unfortunately there isn't much I can do about this and since I'm using this inside of an IXmlSerializable object, I'm forced to use XmlTextReader (which doesn't support things like ReadValueChunk).  This feels like a .NET bug but one that I may be stuck with.  Anyone have any clever ideas?

Comment: Where do you see that `XmlTextReader` doesn't support `ReadValueChunk`?

Comment: Well, in fairness I couldn't find this explicitly in the documentation but if you try it you get a NotSupportedException.  Alternatively you can check CanReadValueChunk on the XmlTextReader and see that it is set to false.